# Concentration (card game) with Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, flashcards

I would like to create a concentration card game (Matching Pairs) with Latex.
On one side, there should be a function and the matching graph. On the otherside should be a logo.

I would like to print it so that the front and back match. I.e. after printing I would only have to cut out the cards.

I have a MWE with a tabular, but:

- Is there a better solution?
- For example, if a graph is accidentally too big, the front and the back don't match anymore.
- The graph is not centered.
- Is there maybe an existing setup?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{array}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{7}
{\centering
\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.25\textwidth}|}}\hline
$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ &  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,>=latex,font= \footnotesize]
\begin{axis}[axis lines = middle,domain=-2.3:2.3,xmin=-5.3,xmax=5.3,ymin=-5.3, ymax=5.3,x=.25cm,y=.25cm]
\addplot[very thick,blue ] {1/x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} & & \\ \hline
& & & \\ \hline
& & & \\ \hline
& & & \\ \hline
& & & \\ \hline
& & & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}

\newpage 

\renewcommand\arraystretch{7}
\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{p{0.25\textwidth}|}}\hline
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-1x1} & & & \\ \hline
& & & \\ \hline
& & & \\ \hline
& & & \\ \hline
& & & \\ \hline
& & & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```